# Make Android "SlidingPaneLayout" push actionbar too

Tags: android, slidingmenu, slidingpanelayout

I am using `android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout` to make a sliding menu. Alas, `SlidingPaneLayout` only pushes main contents, and does not include the action bar. I want this layout to push the action bar too!

I would like the layout like this:

[image: SlidingPaneLayout wiht action bar]

Comment: I suggest to make the whole menu as a new activity since when you really look at it why would the drawer icon be changed into navigate back icon wherein the default on Navigation drawer just animates the icon. So based on it you will just call a new intent for the menu and implement a custom animation and overridePendingTransition. Never tried it before that is why I'm saying this on a comment but I guess that will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Sorry for poor English. Please somebody edit this answer.)

Finally, I solved this problem! I inspired by [this project](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

In short,

ActionbarActivity has view hierarchy like this (but different version has different hierarchy! this example is hierarchy of android 2.3 gingerbread.).

```
A(decorView)--- B(FrameLayout)--- C(LinearLayout)--- D(Layout including actionbar)
                                                 \__ E(Layout including contents)
```

1. remove `B` from `A`
2. inflate SlidingPaneLayout (called F)
3. inflate sliding menu's view (called G)
4. add G into F
5. add  into F
6. add F into A

and result.

```
A(decorView)--- F(SlidingPaneLayout)--- G(sliding menu view)
                                    \__ B(FrameLayout)--- C(LinearLayout)--- D(Layout including actionbar)
                                                                         \__ E(Layout including contents)
```

application codes in below

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @InjectView(R.id.hello)
    TextView mTextView;
    @InjectView(R.id.call_menu)
    Button mCallMenu;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        //get A
        ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView();

        //get B
        ViewGroup viewIncludingAction = (ViewGroup) parentView.getChildAt(0);

        //maintain background theme
        TypedArray a = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] {android.R.attr.windowBackground});
        int background = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
        a.recycle();
        viewIncludingAction.setBackgroundResource(background);

        //remove B
        parentView.removeView(viewIncludingAction);

        //inflate F
        final ViewGroup paneLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_slide_pane, null, false);

        //inflate G
        View menuView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_side_menu, paneLayout, false);

        //because there's no default padding for status bar, add it mint result = 0;
        int result = 0;
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        menuView.setPadding(0, result, 0, 0);

        //process 4~6
        paneLayout.addView(menuView);
        paneLayout.addView(viewIncludingAction);
        parentView.addView(paneLayout);


        mCallMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onClick(View view) {
                ((SlidingPaneLayout)paneLayout).openPane();
        }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/call_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/hello"
        android:text="pop"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_side_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="TEST"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

view_slid_pane.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution.
Using setSupportActionBar instead of default actionBar.

First add `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>` into your theme.

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/sliding_pane_layout">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLeft"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameRight"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_swipe);
    //setSupportActionBar((Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar));
    SlidingPaneLayout slidingPaneLayout = (SlidingPaneLayout)findViewById(R.id.sliding_pane_layout);
    slidingPaneLayout.setPanelSlideListener(this);
    slidingPaneLayout.setCoveredFadeColor(0xffff0000);


    Fragment fragment1 = new SideFragment();
    Fragment fragment2 = new ContentFragment();


    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.frameLeft, fragment1);
    ft.replace(R.id.frameRight, fragment2);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);//设置动画效果
    ft.commit();
}
```

ContentFragment.java

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_content, container, false);
    ActionBarActivity a = (ActionBarActivity)getActivity();
    a.setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar));
    return view;
}
```

fragment_content.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@color/red_800"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        sothree:theme="@style/ActionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the accepted answer will not be work for all the Android api. I write the below code and it works fine.

In my toolbar I set two buttons (one left and one right) and also I set the title of screen in center of toolbar. It's easy to add everything you want in toolbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <!-- left slide panel contains the ListView -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_panel"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

        <!-- right panel which contains content of fragment & toolbar -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/right_panel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <!-- toolbar -->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

                <!-- menu button -->
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar_menu_button"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/sliding_panel_button" />

                <!-- toolbar title -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <!-- messages button -->
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar_messages_button"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/action_bar_messages"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </FrameLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```